# '__post_init__' or dynamically create new fields of SQLModel after initiation

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic, sqlmodel

My objective is to create a new field based on another field after a `Request` is posted to FastAPI. My attempt was:

```py
import functools
from datetime import date, datetime

from slugify import slugify
from sqlmodel import Field, SQLModel


class ProjectBase(SQLModel):
    is_active: bool = Field(default=True, nullable=False)
    name: str = Field(..., nullable=False)

    publish_date: date = Field(default_factory=datetime.now().date, nullable=False)
    
    # # post_init
    repr_name: str = Field(
        default_factory=functools.partial(slugify, name, separator='_'),
        description="The project represented name, it must contain no whitespace, each word is separated by an underscore and it is slugified using the python-slugify library.",
        nullable=False)
```

I have also tried `__post_init__` but I think SQLModel does not have such a mechanism, it belongs to `dataclasses` within `pydantic`.

My desired output would be something like if a `Request` like the below was POST-ed:

```
request = {
    'is_active': true,
    'name': 'hello world bye',
    'publish_date': '2023-01-01'
}
```

Then, the following `Response` is gotten and inserted into the database:

```
response = {
    'is_active': true,
    'name': 'hello world bye',
    'repr_name': 'hello_world_bye', # output of slugify(`name`, separator='_')
    'publish_date': '2023-01-01'
}
```

Comment: I don't believe the model system is not designed for use cases like this. Any model should be static, so that it can be statically analysed. Although what you can do can be likely achieved, it could be more maintainable problem just to model your data with optional fields.

Comment: Please make sure to always include relevant **import**s in your code snippets to make them complete and reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankfully `sqlmodel.SQLModel` inherits from `pydantic.BaseModel`. (And their metaclasses are also related.)

This is yet another job for custom [validators](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/). We just need a default sentinel value to check against, if no explicit value is provided by the user. I would just make the field type a union of `str` and `None` and make `None` the default, but then always ensure a `str` ends up as the value via the validator.

Here is an example:

```py
from datetime import date, datetime
from typing import Any, Optional

from pydantic import validator
from slugify import slugify
from sqlmodel import Field, SQLModel


class ProjectBase(SQLModel):
    name: str = Field(..., nullable=False)
    publish_date: date = Field(default_factory=datetime.now().date, nullable=False)
    repr_name: Optional[str] = Field(default=None, nullable=False)

    @validator("repr_name", always=True)
    def slugify_name(cls, v: Optional[str], values: dict[str, Any]) -> str:
        if v is None:
            return slugify(values["name"], separator="_")
        return slugify(v, separator="_")


print(ProjectBase(name="foo bar baz").json(indent=2))
print(ProjectBase(name="spam", repr_name="Eggs and Bacon").json(indent=2))
```

Output:

```json
{
  "name": "foo bar baz",
  "publish_date": "2023-02-11",
  "repr_name": "foo_bar_baz"
}
```

```json
{
  "name": "spam",
  "publish_date": "2023-02-11",
  "repr_name": "eggs_and_bacon"
}
```

The [`always=True`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/#validate-always) is important to trigger validation, when no value was explicitly provided.

The order of the fields is also important because the `values` dictionary in the validator method will only contain previously validated fields and field validation occurs in the order the fields were defined (see docs link above), so since `name` comes before `repr_name`, it will be validated and its value therefore present in the dictionary, when `repr_name` validation is triggered.

**Important:** Validation will [**not work**](https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/issues/52#issuecomment-1311987732), if the validators belong to a `table=True` model. To get around this, define a base model with the fields you need validated and inherit from that in your `table=True` model; then parse data through the parent model before instantiating the table model with it.

This bit seems pretty limiting, so I would not rule out the possibility that this will change in the future, at least to a certain extent. But in the current state of SQLModel that is what we have.

Comment: Hi sir, sadly when I used your codes, I encountered an error: ```return slugify(values["name"], separator="_")
2023-02-18 00:52:44 KeyError: 'name'```, the field `repr_name` is after `name` field.